# Why do I get a ForeignKey constraint violation

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

As can be seen below, I have 2 models connected via an intermediary model to form a ManyToMany relationship. The problem is that, when I delete a Tender object in get this error.

```js
update or delete on table "tender_details_tender" violates foreign key constraint "user_account_company_tender_id_984ea78c_fk_tender_de" on table "user_account_companyprofile_assignedTenders"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "user_account_companyprofile_assignedTenders".
```

I thought by adding on_delete=models.CASCADE in the ForeighKeys (i.e. in the intermediary model) would solve this problem, but apparently not.

```js
class CompanyProfile(models.Model):
      assignedTenders = models.ManyToManyField(Tender, through='UsersTenders', related_name='UserCompanies')
      
      

# connects users to the tenders they match.  
class UsersTenders(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userTenderLink')
    tender = models.ForeignKey(Tender, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userTenderLink')
    sent = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("user", "tender")
        
        
class Tender(models.Model):
    tenderCategory = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=False)       #this field holds the tender category, e.g. construction, engineering, human resources etc.
    tenderProvince = models.ManyToManyField(Province, blank=False)       #this is the province the tender was a
```

For what its worth, I know what is causing this problem, what I don't know is how to fix it. The problem is that initially I had the ManyToManyField under the CompanyProfile model without the "through" argument, so as you might imagine Django created it's own intermediary table which is "user_account_companyprofile_assignedTenders" as shown in the error. I later decided to create my own intermediary model (i.e. UsersTenders) because I wanted an extra field there, so I had to add the "through" argument in my ManyToManyField (i.e. 'assignedTenders'). That worked fine but the old intermediary model "user_account_companyprofile_assignedTenders" did not get deleted automatically, I assume its because a few relationship had be created before the change. How can I delete "user_account_companyprofile_assignedTenders" without destabilizing my project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add on_delete after database migration? If so have you made a migration after adding on_delete?

You could try to set null=True to all fields and then try ti figure out which foreign key is causing problems.

bdw. when you set blank=True that only means that your form fields will not insist on this fields to be filled for submitting.